# Can not power off my gnome

Tags: 16.04, gnome, shutdown, reboot

I have installed gnome recently on my laptop, but I can neither power off nor reboot it. It does not work with the `sudo` command, too.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: 16.04.3 LTS 64-bit